# PDO Query, WHERE x like ? isn't returning any results

Tags: sql, pdo

I'm currently switching my site over to PDO and I'm running into a few issues, and sadly I don't know enough to figure it out.

I have this query

```
$localnewssql = "SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.headline, n.tagline, n.body, n.tags, n.date, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID
        WHERE n.tags LIKE ? 
        ORDER BY n.date DESC LIMIT 0, 6";
$param = "%sennen%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($localnewssql);
$stmt->execute($param);
$localnews_data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

but nothing is being returned when I foreach loop `$localnews_data`. Can someone please help me understand this?

My old MySQL code which was returning results was:

```
$localnewssql = "SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.tags, n.date, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID
        WHERE n.tags LIKE '%sennen%' 
        ORDER BY n.date DESC LIMIT 0, 6";
$localnewsresult = mysqli_query($conn,$localnewssql);
```

Not sure why the PDO version is returning a blank array?

any ideas?
many thanks

Comment: Do not quote the placeholder, `?`.

Comment: thank you @Parfait, still returning an empty array tho? i've updated my code with your edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of parameter values to [`PDOStatement::execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), where you are passing only a string. Put `$param` in an array and it will work i.e.

```
$stmt->execute(array($param));
```

Comment: life saver, thank you very much!! :D